# How to wrap Scala for comprehension to resolve Future around Play's Form folding?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

I have an action which processes form submissions. Before validating the form, I need to resolve two Futures. I thought I could just nest everything, meaning put the `fold` inside the `yield` block of the for comprehension.

For example:

```
  def handleFormSubmission = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    for {
      user <- userService.findOneByUserId(userId)
      avatar <- avatarService.findOneByUserId(userId)
    } yield {
      myForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => formWithErrorsBranch(formWithErrors, user, avatar),
        changeData => changeDataBranch(changeData, user, avatar))
    }
  }
```

Both branches return `Future[Result]` and the signature of `fold` is `def fold[R](hasErrors: Form[T] => R, success: T => R): R`. To my understanding, `fold` takes two functions with an argument `Form[T]` and `T` and both return `R`. That would mean that if I return in both branches `Future[Result]`, `fold` will also return `Future[Result]`. However, since it is wrapped inside a for comprehension to resolve both Futures `user` and `avatar`, I would not need to have `Future[Result]` but instead `Result`. Is that correct? If so, how can I fix the following compile error in a non-blocking manner?

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
 required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is how it can be solved:

```
  def handleFormSubmission = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    for {
      user <- userService.findOneByUserId(userId)
      avatar <- avatarService.findOneByUserId(userId)
      response <- myForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => formWithErrorsBranch(formWithErrors, user, avatar),
        changeData => changeDataBranch(changeData, user, avatar)
      )
    } yield response
  }
```

simply, don't yield so soon. If you are writing for comprehension and something is returning future, extract the value with `<-` and then yield it.

`<-` is translated into `flatMap` with signature (simplified) `flatMap(f: A => Future[B]): Future[B]`. So if your function returns a future and you don't want to get nested `Future[Future[A]]`, use `flatMap`. `yield` is desugared to `map` with signature `map(f: A => B): Future[B]` so this is for the case when `f` does not return a `Future` unless you want it nested for some reason. If both of your branches for folding on form binding result return a `Future[A]` then you want to use `flatMap`.

On a side note, you are not obtaining user and avatar concurrently, but one after another. You might want to start the computations first and then "wait" for both to complete. This can be done in several ways, for example:

```
val userFuture = userService.findOneByUserId(userId)
val avatarFuture = avatarService.findOneByUserId(userId)
for {
  user <- userFuture
  avatar <- avatarFuture
  response <- ...
} yield response
```

or for example with `zip`

```
for {
  (user, avatar) <- userService.findOneByUserId(userId) zip avatarService.findOneByUserId(userId)
  response <- ...
} yield response
```

Answer (score 0):

**Zip and flatMap**

`zip` to the get the resultant `future` and then `flatMap` to create the result.

`recover` in case the zipped future fails.

```
def handleFormSubmission = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>

    val userFuture = userService.findOneByUserId(userId)
    val avatarFuture = avatarService.findOneByUserId(userId)

    userFuture.zip(avatarFuture).flatMap { case (user, avatar) =>

      myForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => formWithErrorsBranch(formWithErrors, user, avatar),
        changeData => changeDataBranch(changeData, user, avatar))

    }.recover { case th =>

      Ok("error occurred because: " + th.getMessage)

    }

  }
```